# The gems of the files executed in a shell by Rails have to be in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

If I run a script from rails and that script requires a gem that is not found in Gemfile it does not work, however the script executed has nothing to do with Rails should behave the same as if you executed anything else like an ls for example

example: /tmp/fichero.rb

```
     #! /usr/bin/env ruby
     #encoding: utf-8

     require "rubygems"
     require 'choice'
     require 'fileutils'
     ...
     ...
```

Gemfile

```
    ...
    ...
    #gem 'choice'
    ...
    ...
```

controller:

```
    stmt = "ruby /tmp/fichero.rb -p hola"
    stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(stmt)
```

or

```
    stmt = "ruby /tmp/fichero.rb -p hola"
    %x[#{stmt}]
```

both:

## `require': cannot load such file -- choice (LoadError)

if I change Gemfile:

```
    ...
    ...
    gem 'choice'
    ...
    ...
```

## It works but I don't want this gem in my Gemfile

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[bundle exec - Shelling-out](https://bundler.io/v1.17/man/bundle-exec.1.html#Shelling-out)

Any Ruby code that opens a subshell (like system, backticks, or %x{}) will automatically use the current Bundler environment. If you need to shell out to a Ruby command that is not part of your current bundle, use the with_clean_env method with a block. Any subshells created inside the block will be given the environment present before Bundler was activated. For example, Homebrew commands run Ruby, but don't work inside a bundle:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  `brew install wget`
end
```